# Another Data Science Milestone, our first 10k User!

Tags: discussion, reputation

I am am not sure how to phrase this as a question, so I am not going bother.  [NeilSlater](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/836/neil-slater) just crossed the [10k threshold](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) here on Data Science.  And I think it is time for a bit of celebration. Please join me in congratulating Neil.

[image]

He is doing yeoman's work, not only patiently answering many questions, but also actively working in comments, getting questions banged into shape. In addition to DS, he is ~10k on [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8364/neil-slater), and 20k on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001031/neil-slater) where he holds a [Gold Badge in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/227/ruby?userid=2001031).

So, congrats to Data Science and especially, congrats and thanks to Neil, virtual High Fives around.

[image: High Five 1] [image: High Five 2]

Comment: Woohoo!  Congrats Neil!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing . . .

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/jbwsLn6OvdO80/giphy.gif]

. . . but thank you!

I'm doing my best to upvote all good questions and answers I see too, so we hit more milestones.

Comment: Congratulations, I'm so happy for you and our community.

Comment: Nice Gif. Congrats Neil. :)

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cong! @Neil_Slater is a great contributor to neural networks. Keep up the good works!