# The user gets reputation points for editing after having 1000 points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

As I have seen, +2 reputation points are given when a user's edit suggestion is approved by their peers.

Once a user gets 1000 reputation points, he has the possibility of editing without being peer-reviewed, so there are no points given.

I have noticed that people's reputation tends to slow down after 1000 points? Should this be considered normal?

Answer (score 3):

There are only 50 users on the site who have [20 or more edits](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all).  So there are not that many users who could even have gotten all that much reputation from editing alone.

I would suggest that if peoples' reputation gains, slow down after some time, it maybe more to that fact that participating takes an investment of time and energy.  The conditions and desires that allow someone to make that investment, are likely to change as the calendar progresses.

There are [users](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/836/neil-slater) who have managed to gather [lot's of reputation](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/another-data-science-milestone-our-first-10k-user) but they are not the norm.

Comment: I don't mean from editing alone, I mean 1000 points overall. After 1000 points, the editing doesn't give any points.

Comment: @Stephen Why does it not reward users anymore for editing? Is it because he/she is free to edit now any question any time?

Comment: @KiriteeGak, Yes, once you can edit without review there is no more +2 per approved edit.  Also after 500 +2's (1000 points total) from edits also no more +2's